# Crear columna ID basada en una frecuencia de días y horas

Tags: pandas, datetime

Tengo un dataframe en Pandas similar a éste:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['22/07/2022 05:37:59', '22/07/2022 07:45:22', '22/07/2022 07:40:51', '23/07/2022 08:37:59', '23/07/2022 12:22:00', '24/07/2022 07:15:59', '24/07/2022 09:16:59', '24/07/2022 15:00:02', '24/07/2022 15:24:10'],
    'Name': ['Josh', 'George', 'Hayden', 'George', 'Josh', 'Peter', 'Josh', 'Hayden', 'Peter']})

df

                 Date    Name
0 2022-07-22 05:37:59    Josh
1 2022-07-22 07:45:22  George
2 2022-07-22 07:40:51  Hayden
3 2022-07-23 08:37:59  George
4 2022-07-23 12:22:00    Josh
5 2022-07-24 07:15:59   Peter
6 2022-07-24 09:16:59    Josh
7 2022-07-24 15:00:02  Hayden
8 2022-07-24 15:24:10   Peter
```

La columna Date la transformo a datetime64[ns]. Estoy intentando crear una nueva columna que llamaría ID que agruparía cada día. Por ejemplo, todos los días 22-7 tendrían una ID 1, los días 23, ID 2, etc. Además, habría una excepción. Si han pasado más de 5 horas entre un registro y otro, aunque estemos en el mismo día, la ID sería distinta. En el ejemplo de arriba, entre la fila 6 y 7 sería donde se produciría ese salto porque habrían pasado más de esas 5 horas. El resultado final sería el siguiente:

```
                 Date    Name   ID
0 2022-07-22 05:37:59    Josh    1
1 2022-07-22 07:45:22  George    1
2 2022-07-22 07:40:51  Hayden    1
3 2022-07-23 08:37:59  George    2
4 2022-07-23 12:22:00    Josh    2
5 2022-07-24 07:15:59   Peter    3
6 2022-07-24 09:16:59    Josh    3
7 2022-07-24 15:00:02  Hayden    4
8 2022-07-24 15:24:10   Peter    4
```

He intentado conseguirlo con un cumsum y shift pero con este código no logro el resultado esperado, puesto que me genera una ID 1 para el primero pero después, a pesar de ser en el mismo día me encuentro con ID 2 tanto en la segunda como en la tercera fila del mismo día 22-7:

```
df['ID'] = pd.Series(np.where(df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift(1) < pd.Timedelta(5,'H'),1,0).cumsum()).shift(-1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo podría conseguirlo? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, el truco está en utilizar el accesor [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) de la columna `Date` (Es un requisito previo que `Date` sea de tipo `datetime64[ns]`).

A través de ese accesor podemos obtener el número de día (Entre muchas otras cosas empezando por [date](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), te recomiendo ver la documentación).

Tu máscara (Filtro) tiene dos condiciones, la primera es que las fechas sean en día diferente, (En este ejemplo voy a suponer que todas tus fechas pertenecen al mismo año, pero en caso contrario podrías utilizar otros elementos de `dt`) y si la diferencia es de más de 5 horas aunque estén en el mismo día.

Para obtener la diferencia de días podemos utilizar lo siguiente:

```
df['Date'].dt.day - df['Date'].dt.day.shift() > 0
```

Para obtener la diferencia de horas podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
(df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift()).dt.total_seconds() > 18000
```

**Nota:** 18000 segundos son 5 horas.

Si combinamos las dos partes para obtener nuestra máscara `mask` resultaría el siguiente código

```
mask = ((df['Date'].dt.day - df['Date'].dt.day.shift() > 0) | ((df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift()).dt.total_seconds() > 18000))
print(mask)
```

Esto devolvería una serie de booleanos de la siguiente forma:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8    False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Y por último podemos obtener el grupo con `where` y `cumsum` casi como lo tenías:

```
pd.Series(np.where(mask,1,0).cumsum()).add(1)
```

**Nota:** Se agrega 1 al final para que los grupos inicien con "ID" 1

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['22/07/2022 05:37:59', '22/07/2022 07:45:22', '22/07/2022 07:40:51', '23/07/2022 08:37:59', '23/07/2022 12:22:00', '24/07/2022 07:15:59', '24/07/2022 09:16:59', '24/07/2022 15:00:02', '24/07/2022 15:24:10'],
    'Name': ['Josh', 'George', 'Hayden', 'George', 'Josh', 'Peter', 'Josh', 'Hayden', 'Peter']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

mask = ((df['Date'].dt.day - df['Date'].dt.day.shift() > 0) | ((df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift()).dt.total_seconds() > 18000))
df['ID'] = pd.Series(np.where(mask,1,0).cumsum()).add(1)
print(df)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Date                Name    ID
0   2022-07-22 05:37:59 Josh    1
1   2022-07-22 07:45:22 George  1
2   2022-07-22 07:40:51 Hayden  1
3   2022-07-23 08:37:59 George  2
4   2022-07-23 12:22:00 Josh    2
5   2022-07-24 07:15:59 Peter   3
6   2022-07-24 09:16:59 Josh    3
7   2022-07-24 15:00:02 Hayden  4
8   2022-07-24 15:24:10 Peter   4
```

Comment: Lo primero, mil gracias. Funciona casi casi casi jeje No sé por qué pero en mi df real (unas 240 filas, unas 20 por día y en algunos días 40, 20 más o menos a una hora y otros 20 unas 5 horas más tarde), la última fila de cada ID me la marca como ID+1. Y en la última fila me sale nulo. A ver si doy con qué podría ser

Comment: @nokvk, tal vez el formato de la fecha no está bien en esa fila, intenta probar la máscara por separado en esa fila específica y vas a ver la condición que se cumple. Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Perfecto, ya está todo solucionado. El código es correcto, era un problema en mi df, que no sé por qué motivo tenía alguna fila suelta sin sentido. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: No hay de que. Saludos!